# Android VideoView not playing mp4 files

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

I have already seen most of the questions here but none of them helps.

Following is Streaming url it works perfectly on VLC and browser but it can't be played in android app.

Here is my code

```
public class VideoDemo extends Activity {
    private VideoView video;
    private MediaController ctlr;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

       /* File clip = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "90.mp4");*/

       /* if (clip.exists()) {*/
            video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
            //video.setVideoPath(clip.getAbsolutePath());
             video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://103.50.152.102:9096/LubrizolWebPrj/service/getEnqVideo/90"));
            video.requestFocus();
            video.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    video.start();
                }
            });
        //}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

MP4 is just a container - the video and audio stream inside it will both be encoded in different formats.

Android natively only supports certain types of formats. There is a list here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Make sure the video and audio encoding type is supported. Just because it says "mp4" doesn't automatically mean it should be playable.

Though if your format is not supported, Try using [YoutubeVideoView](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)

Comment: But it is recorded with same device and can be played from inbuilt video player if i put video on sdcard